# How to send a POST request with native PHP?

Tags: php, http, post

I have a requirement to send a POST request with php, but without enabling any extensions.

I searched all over the internet but all I could found are solutions like cURL, PECL etc.

Is there any way to do this without any extensions?

Comment: I would think [streams](http://php.net/manual/en/context.http.php#refsect1-context.http-examples) would fit, but I don't know if it fits the extension-less requirement.

Comment: You could try using sockets or streams

Comment: @JaredFarrish Thanks, but the `extension-less` part is actually the keyword  of the question. 
@Andreas Do they come with native php?

Comment: As far as i know you can use sockets without any extension. Give it a try.

Comment: Do you know that "streams require an extension"? I don't. If you do, then there you go. Edit: Apparently it is a "basic extension", however so are [sockets](http://php.net/manual/en/sockets.installation.php): http://php.net/manual/en/refs.basic.other.php